# Asynchronous calls from within sockjs-tornado methods

Tags: websocket, socket.io, tornado, sockjs

I am building a server on [sockjs-tornado](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado), and wonder how could one take advantage of tornado's asynchronous HTTP client -- or other asynchronous facilities for tornado such as asyncmongo, tornado-redis, etc. Apparently it is not possible to use the `tornado.web.asynchronous` & `tornado.gen.engine` decorators on random methods. So if I need to do asynchronous Mongo/HTTP/Redis calls from within SockJSConnection's `on_message()`, how would I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is to create a method (or a function) which is decorated by tornado.gen decorator

Created small gist to illustrate how you can do it: https://gist.github.com/3708549

If you will run sample and check server console, you'll see following output:

1 - Making request

2 - Returned from on_message

... slight delay ...

3 - Sent data to client

So, it is not blocking ioloop and makes HTTP call in background.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the insight -- I was surprised to find out that the on_* callbacks are asynchronous by default in sockjs-tornado. This is not the case with get/post handler methods of tornado RequestHandlers, where the @asynchronous decorator is necessary to achieve this behaviour. So I was using it (together with gen.engine) and the former was throwing an exception. It appears sockjs-tornado is one step forward :)

Comment: @Joes, in your gist, do you also need to do `self.finish()` at the end of `handle_request` method?

Comment: No, you don't have to call self.finish() - just use your asynchronous methods.

Comment: @Joes, can you actually just decorate `on_message` method itself in sockjs-tornado using `tornado.gen`? Is that same as decorating a separate method which you call within `on_message`?

Comment: Yes, ``on_message`` can be decorated and it will work as expected.